# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - 'previous-application-identifiers' ApplicationLoader rejection

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, testflight, application-loader

Getting an error message when trying to submit to apple either using deliver or application loader.

> ERROR ITMS-90045: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, key 'previous-application-identifiers'
>   in 'Payload/YourApp.app/YourApp' is not supported."

Some background:

- Did an app transfer that resulted in the new app having a slightly different bundle ID (i.e. the team identifier was different)
- Went through the process with Apple to get a special provisioning entitlement that allows you install your freshly transferred app over the existing one.
- Regenerated all profiles.  The Adhoc build works as expected and can installs over the existing App Store app.

Everything seems fine, but just can't submit to apple....

Anyone experience this or have any suggestions?

See the end of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2319/_index.html for some more info on the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with Apple tech support.  The solution was to revoke all distribution certificates and delete all distribution profiles and regenerate them with the required entitlements after they finished adding the extra entitlement to the Account.

Comment: Apple needs to add this entitlement specifically to the developer account? Where do I see if and when it's available?

Comment: "after they finished adding the extra entitlement to the Account." where do they add it? Do they edit the app id?